# Giving an rdp session it's own keyboard and mouse

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, windows-8.1, remote-desktop, mouse

I'm using windows 8 pro on my computer and the client computer.

I want to be able to use my computer, with it's keyboard and mouse on monitor #1, while someone else is in an RDP session on monitor #2, also having there own keyboard and mouse.

Is this possible?

Comment: There was a company that did something sorta like this.  Microsoft basically threatened them into killing the product, claiming that the company was violating the Windows EULA.  Microsoft was fine if they used a Server edition of Windows with an appropriate number of TS cals.

Comment: This wouldn't be like a server scenario with multiple users/same OS, Just a normal RDP session. Two separate and paid for Operating systems. I was just simply wondering if an RDP session can have it's own keyboard/mouse?